# Swift: keyboard blocking text view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a Text View at the bottom of a UIView, so when touch the text view and the keyboard shows up, the keyboard will block the text view.
How can I solve this problem?
Can I make the whole UIView move up when the keyboard shows up? so that the keyboard will not block anything

Answer (score 4):

> Can I make the whole UIView move up when the keyboard shows up?

You certainly can. Just shift it up, as I do [in this example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p520textFieldSliding/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift).

Another way is to put your whole interface into a UIScrollView - not enabled so that the *user* can scroll it, but so that *you* can scroll it. When the keyboard appears, you change the content inset and scroll up, and when the keyboard disappears, you reverse that. [Here's my example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift) of that approach.

Comment: Content insets are the way to go